# Laravel 5 check validation error on field and rule

Tags: laravel, validation

I want to change status code when rules are different on validation, checkout the comment  before `if(isset($ValidationResponse['email']['required'])){` in code

```
public function checkCustomerEmail_Method(Request $request){
        $checkCustomerEmail_rules =  ['email'=>'required|exists:userstable,Email];
        $messages = [
                'required'=>trans('general.mandatory',['type'=>'Email']),
                'exists'=>trans('general.field_notexists',['field'=>'Email'])
        ];

        $ValidationResponse = Validator::make($request->input(),$checkCustomerEmail_rules,$messages);
        $userEmail = $request->input('email');
        if($ValidationResponse->fails()){
            ///Here I can work on that condition
            if(isset($ValidationResponse['email']['exists'])){
                $error_status = 204;
            }
             return response()->json(['error'=>true,'errormsg'=>$ValidationResponse->errors()->first(),'success'=>false],$error_status);

         }

 }
```

Comment: What is the error you're seeing with your code?

Comment: @ChrisPhillips "Cannot use object of type Illuminate\\Validation\\Validator as array"
also I have try code as object `$ValidationResponse->email->exists`

Comment: Did my answer below help?  Did it not work?

Answer (score 0):

It has been a little while since I've worked with laravel validations.  But you could always break it into 2 validation calls.  1 for the email exists, and 1 for the rest.

```
public function checkCustomerEmail_Method(Request $request){
        $checkEmailExists_rules = ['email'=>'exists:userstable,Email];
        $ValidationResponse = Validator::make($request->input(),$checkEmailExists_rules,$messages);
         if($ValidationResponse->fails()){
         {
            // Return you 204 message
         }

        $checkCustomerEmail_rules =  ['email'=>'required|exists:userstable,Email];
        $messages = [
                'required'=>trans('general.mandatory',['type'=>'Email']),
                'exists'=>trans('general.field_notexists',['field'=>'Email'])
        ];

        $ValidationResponse = Validator::make($request->input(),$checkCustomerEmail_rules,$messages);
        $userEmail = $request->input('email');
        if($ValidationResponse->fails()){
            // Return standard validation failure message (422)?

         }

 }
```